# EJBAccessException when invoke local EJB on Wildfly

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

When I try to invoke local EJB I get EJBAccessException running my migrated Glassfish web application on Wildfly 8.2. I found the JBoss documentation all other than strait forward and need help, i.e. no link to JBoss documentation please.

I have no `@DeclareRoles` notation on my EJB to make it simple for now. I tried with and without using the security realm `other` adding jboss-web and jboss-ejb3 to tie the bean to a realm. But I still get the same exception.

I've read these tutorials, but can't get it to work. I am using MongoDB and JDBC security realm setup don't help me much. But for now I bypass the user-role authentication.

[Migrating a Java EE App from GlassFish to WildFly](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/)

[Invoke EJB from WildFly safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217561/invoke-ejb-from-wildfly-safely)
And others

How can I run local EJB on Wildfly in my web application?

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    public String sayHello() {
    ...
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
     <security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

jboss-ejb3.xml

```
<assembly-descriptor>
    <s:security>
        <!-- Even wildcard * is supported -->
        <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
        <!-- Name of the security domain which is configured in the EJB3 subsystem -->
        <s:security-domain>other</s:security-domain>
    </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WildFly 8, such methods which have no explicit security configurations, in a secured bean, will be treated similar to a method with `@DenyAll` configuration.

This behaviour can be controlled via the `jboss-ejb3.xml` deployment descriptor at a per bean level or a per deployment level as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:jboss
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
        version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <!-- Even wildcard * is supported where * is equivalent to all EJBs in the deployment -->
            <ejb-name>FooBean</ejb-name>
            <s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>false</s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:jboss>
```

Setting `missing-method-permissions-deny-access` to `false` allows access to such methods for all users i.e. the behaviour will be switched to be similar to `@PermitAll`.

Comment: Thanks, by using "*" for ejb-name in my jboss-ejb3.xml I could test without a security realm. Next step is to switch on role and user authentication.